# QuickSearch - is it possible to exclude some contact types?

Tags: contact-types, quicksearch

Is it possible to limit the QuickSearch in the menu bar so it doesn't show some contact types? We have some that are inappropriate to show for this purpose. Eg - we don't need to show leads, only fully established contacts. We don't need to show households, only individuals (because we have cleverly re-used the household functionality to become yoga classes!)

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Very good question and enhancement request. I can see the utility for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afraid to say its not possible at the moment via UI, but you can achieve this by writing a small extension and implementing hook.